# How to create a dialog with available qualities of DASH content in ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer

I am using Exoplayer in my application and I want to show DashMediaSource.
I did it and the video will play this Code:

```
 DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "ExoPlayer"));
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
    DashMediaSource dashMediaSource = new DashMediaSource(uri, dataSourceFactory,
      new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory), null, null);

    BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));

    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

    simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
    player.prepare(dashMediaSource);
```

But I need to show the user a selector for the quality of this vide0.

I just want to get all available qualities from my dash file and show it to the use.

In `ExoPlayer 1.5.8`, I used `getTrackCount()` to get all available qualities but in `ExoPlayer 2.5.3` it is not available anymore.

How can I do that?

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using AnalyticsListener?

```
player.addAnalyticsListener(new AnalyticsListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBandwidthEstimate(EventTime eventTime, int totalLoadTimeMs, long totalBytesLoaded, long bitrateEstimate) {

            }
        });
```